# Is there a C# format specifier that will omit the leading zero unless the value is zero?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, format-specifiers

In other words, I want 0.123 to show as ".123", but 0 should show as "0".  Currently the best I've got is

```
String.Format("{0:.###}", n)
```

which gives ".123" for 0.123, but "" (the empty string) for 0.

Comment: `String.Format("{0:0.###}", n)` if changed to this will yield `0` but if you type `0.123` the value will return the leading `0` in front.. you can do 2 things, keep the Format the same as what you have and convert the `""` value to `0` or change the string format to be `String.Format("{0:0.###}", n)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `;` as a separator, you can specify formats for positive, negative, and zero values.  `string.Format("{0:.###;-.###;0}", n)` will display '0' when `n==0` and will leave off the leading zero for positive and negative values.  Check the MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

if all else fails you could do something like:

```
 string s = n == 0 ? "0" : String.Format("{0:.###}", n);
```

not brilliant, but will get the job done :-)

Comment: +1 I'd personally approach the problem more like this. It's simple, it's straight forward, and it works. What else do you want in code?

Comment: This is how I'd normally do it, but I was using it in the StringFormat attribute of of a XAML binding, so I wanted to do it all with one format string.

I ended up doing something similar to your answer anyway though, because it was clearer, so have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

here is something you can try I added a place where you can test the code and change the variable from `0` to `.1234` to test

```
var decNum =.1234;//change to 0 will return 0 change to .1234 will return the correct formatted value

var formatDecil = String.Format("{0:.###}", decNum);
formatDecil = string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatDecil) ? 0.ToString():formatDecil;
```